# Find out if enqueued script uses wp_localize_script?

Tags: wp-localize-script

Is there a function that can check if an enqueued script has a call to [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) attached to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function is_localized($tag) {

    global $wp_scripts;

    $data = $wp_scripts->get_data( $tag, 'data' );

    return ! empty( $data );
}
```

Comment: As I'm facing a related question right now: There's no `l10n` part inside `extra` (anymore?). It's `array( 'data', 'group' );`.

Comment: @kaiser this stuff keeps changing, updated code